# Unit sphere of a subspace of a complex Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space with a sub-space $H_0\subset \mathcal{H}$. It may be the case that $S_{H_0}:=\{x\in H_0:\, ||x||=1\}$, the unit sphere contained in $H_0$, is not connected.

For example, if $H_0=\text{span}\{x\}$, then $S_{H_0}=\{\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{-x}{\|x\|}\}$ is clearly disconnected. However, if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space, I feel this case cannot arise. I am lacking a rigorous proof for $\text{dim}(H_0)=1$ and even in $\text{dim}(H_0) >1$.

A detailed proof will be of very much help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is always conected as long as $H_0$ is not one-dimensional. $\{x\in H_0: x\neq 0\}$ is connected. [You can find a path between any two points inside the two dimensional subspace containing those two points]. The map $x \to \frac x {\|x\|}$ is continuous on this set and so its image is connected.

Comment: Thank you @Kaviramamurthy. for your answer, whenever $H_0:=span\{x\}$ is one-dimensional, can we not say $S_{H_0}=\{\mu \frac{x}{\|x\|} : |\mu|=1\}$ which is a continuous image of $S^1$ under function $\mu \to \mu \frac{x}{\|x\|}$, thus connected. I just came out with the idea today.